# LayoutParams: how to put button at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put a button at the bottom of a webview. For some reason, it keeps showing up at the top. Here's my code:

```
    webview = new WebView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setId(11);
    LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //          params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    myButton.setText("A Button!");
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

    webview.setLayoutParams(params2);
    //setBackgroundcolor(0) - You must make the background color transparent before setting backgroundResource
    webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    webview.addView(myButton);
```

Edit --

I'm gonna go ahead and set up the base of my reusable view in xml. I'll just use `ScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` inside of it (containing my `WebView` and `Button`). The reason is because I only want the `Button` to show up once I reach the end of the webpage.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this in XML?

Comment: Yes. I'm gonna be setting up the views based on the intent that fired up this activity. So there's gonna be some internal logic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebView` extends `AbsoluteLayout`, so you can't use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Moreover, `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, and `WebView` is definitely not a view to be used as a container.

You can overlay a `RelativeLayout` over the `WebView` putting them in a `FrameLayout`, they'll get piled up, with the last view added (your RelativeLayout) at the top.

Comment: I didn't paste it in my OP, but the `WebView` is nested inside a `RelativeLayout`. So can I just add the button to my `RelativeLayout`? If so, how do I stick at the bottom, underneath the `WebView`?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: yes, add the button to the relative layout with the parameters suggested by Houcine. If you add it after the WebView, it will be drawn over that.

Answer (score 2):

`WebView` extends `AbsoluteLayout`, not `RelativeLayout`, so adding a rule for a `RelativeLayout` will have no affect. Try setting the layout gravity of the button to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: liked the possibility to do it on runtime!